# How to isolate (select) specific grayscale values from an image to use as a mask in shaders?

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes

I'm wanting to combine image masks into one to save on space, and I know how I would go about doing this in Substance Designer or Unreal Engine, but I can't seem to figure out a method in blender. Ideally (as none of the masks overlap), I'd have each mask as a different grayscale value, and the background as black. Then for each mask within the image, select/isolate the specific grayscale value, increase it to white (likely with the hue/saturation node) and then use that as the masking input.

In Designer I would use one of the histogram nodes to isolate each grayscale value independently and then use a levels node to bring the isolated gray to white, and in Unreal Engine I would likely use the RGB channels to pack in 3 different masks (though this would be more limited due to having a limit of 3). Is there a method similar to either of these? Or is there a completely different way to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: Different _Math_ nodes set to _Compare_ > _Equal_ and then the different values to check against?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann This could work! I just tested it out and I have it working to isolate at least 2 masks within one image, I may have to toy around with it more as I'm not super familiar with math nodes, so thank you!